# IIS7.5 Excel printing not working when run from server

Tags: vba, pdf-generation, iis-7.5, office-interop

I'm having trouble generating a PDF-file with PDFCreator from Excel macro (using VB.NET 3.5 and Interop).
Through Windows login as the domain user I can run the macro directly from Excel and everything works fine (a pdf file is printed and saved), but when published and run as the same user from server there is no printer found.

In the macro I know this can be solved by setting Application.ActivePrinter ("PDFCreator on Ne00:" in my case), which again works when I run directly from Excel but not from server. So what I wonder is how to make it possible to set ActivePrinter when running on server?

It worked with previous IIS version on the server (6.0). I have tried giving the domain user access permissions (e.g. in DCOMCNFG), the PDFCreator is set up correctly and accessible, don't really know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Office Interop from server-like scenarios (IIS/ASP.NET/Windows Service...) is **NOT supported by MS** - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Another point is that since windows vista there have been several security-related changed which prevent doing any "desktop-like" things (for example printing...) from a Windows Service...

**Alternative to Interop:**

To create PDF from Excel file there are several libraries out there which do not use Excel and work fine in server-scenarios - like [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/)...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yahia! I will have a look for an alternative solution.

Comment: you are welcome - please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that is of help

Answer (score 0):

It works even in IIS8 also.
Give Microsoft Excel Application sufficient Permission from DcomConfig  (Eg-IIS_IUSRS,Network Services etc)

take care of impersonate user id and password provided In Web.xml. do not make it true if not necessary. it worked for me when i removed this.